# package not found

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

**package javax.servlet does not exist**

**import javax.servlet.*;**

```
 import javax.servlet.*;

public class FirstServlet implements Servlet{

ServletConfig config;

public void init(ServletConfig config){
    this.config=config;
    System.out.println("we r in init() method");
}

public void service(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response){
    System.out.println("we r in service() method");
}

public void destroy(){
    System.out.println("we r in destroy() method");
}

public ServletConfig getServletConfig(){
    return config;
}

public String getServletInfo(){
    return "FIRSTSERVLET";
}
}
```

*where should the class path be set since i am using tomcat server*

**even after the inclusion of servlet-api.jar still the error persists**

Comment: have you added the jar files in your classpath?

Comment: Which version of tomcat are you using? Its a compile time error. You need to include the servlet jar during compilation.

Comment: i have included the servlet-api.jar file which is present in lib folder of tomcat 7 installation folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the sample "build.xml" file that is included in the Tomcat Application Developers Guide for your version of Tomcat (e.g. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/), it will tell you what needs to go on your build classpath.  (The answer depends on which version of Tomcat you are using ...)

In fact, if you are new to Java development, Servlets and/or Tomcat, I recommend that you spend time reading the entire Guide ... from start to finish.

Comment: i have executed many prgms before. accidentally the class path or path variable which i have set got deleted . if i configure it again its not gettin complied. thts the problm

Comment: @user1560820 - I strongly recommend that you use Ant and a "build.xml" file rather than relying on dodgy environment variable settings.  Read the Guide.